# Change txtbox length on radio btn change ASP.NET and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoCardType" runat="server" onchange="ValidateCCN();" AutoPostBack="false" Width="190px">
     <asp:ListItem Value="Visa">
        <img src="images/visa.gif" /> Visa</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="MC">
        <img src="images/mm.gif" /> Master Card</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="AE">
        <img src="images/ae.gif" /> American Express</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="DC">
        <img src="images/dc.gif" /> Discover</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And the JavaScript is:

```
function ValidateCCN() {
        var y = document.getElementById('ctl00_site_body_txtCscNr');
        var x = document.getElementsByName('ctl00$site_body$rdoCardType');
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i].checked) {
                if (x.value == "AE")
                    y.maxLength = '3';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I missing? Because the length of textbox is not changing. Thanks!

Comment: don't use final name or id to get dom element. try `document.getElementById('<%=ASPNETID%>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be x[i].value -

```
function ValidateCCN() {
    var y = document.getElementById('ctl00_site_body_txtCscNr');
    var x = document.getElementsByName('ctl00$site_body$rdoCardType');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].checked) {
            if (x[i].value == "AE")
                y.maxLength = '3';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```